# How to copy variables from a custom class array on host into a float array on device in CUDA

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda

I am using CUDA. I have the following class on host:

```
class Particle{
     public:
     float x;
     float v;
     // several other variables
}
```

Then I have a vector of particles

```
vector <Particle> p_all(512);
```

On the GPU, I want to operate on an array of all x's (taken from all the Particles), and want to copy the data from the Particles array into a float array on device. I have a hunch that cudaMemcpy can be used, and I tried the following code, but it gives invalid pitch error.

```
cudaMalloc( (void**) &pos_dev, sizeof(float)*512);
cudaMemcpy2D( (void*) &pos_dev, sizeof(float), (void*)&p_all[0].x, sizeof(Particle), sizeof(Particle), 512*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Is it at all possible to do so? Of course, the backup solution is to create an array of x's using a for loop and then copy it to the device. But I am looking for a more efficient solution.

Thanks.

FULL CODE BELOW.

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// This will output the proper error string when calling cudaGetLastError
void getLastCudaError(string s=""){
    string errMessage = s;
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if( err != cudaSuccess){
        cerr << __FILE__ << "(" << __LINE__ << ") : Last Cuda Error - " << errMessage 
             << " (" << int(err) << "): " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << ".\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
}

class Particle{
    public:
    float x;
    float v;
    int a;
    char c;
    short b;

    Particle(){
        a=1988; c='a'; v=5.56; x=1810; b=1.66;
    }
};

template <class T>
void printVec(vector <T> &v, string name = "v"){
    cout << name << " = ";
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) cout << v[i] << " " ;
    cout << '\n';
}

int main(){

    const int N = 512;
    vector <float> pos(N,5);

    vector <Particle> p_all(N);

    float * pos_dev;
    float * vel_dev;

    cudaMalloc( (void**) &pos_dev, sizeof(float)*N);

    printVec(pos, "pos");

    cudaMemcpy2D( (void*) &pos_dev, sizeof(float), (void*)&(p_all[0].x), sizeof(Particle), sizeof(float), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    getLastCudaError("HtoD");

    cudaMemcpy( (void*) &pos[0], (void*)&pos_dev, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    getLastCudaError("DtoH");

    printVec(pos, "pos_new");

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cudaMemcpy2D` call is set up incorrectly.  Check the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g17f3a55e8c9aef5f90b67cdf22851375).

try this instead:

```
cudaMemcpy2D( (void*) pos_dev, sizeof(float), (void*)&(p_all[0].x), sizeof(Particle), sizeof(float), 512, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

There were multiple parameters that needed to be modified, but the invalid pitch error came about because the requested width of transfer in bytes (you had `sizeof(Particle)`) was wider than the destination pitch (`sizeof(float)`, which is correct)

**EDIT:** in addition, although you didn't ask about it, the final `cudaMemcpy` operation in the code you have now posted is also incorrect.  The following changes should help:

```
cudaMemcpy( (void*) &(pos[0]), (void*)pos_dev, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still gives "invalid argument" error. I checked the documentation but I don't quite understand it. I have added the full code to my post, in case you would like to compile. - Thanks.

Comment: Oh now I understand the documentation. But the error still persists. - Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the first parameter.  memcpy operations want a single pointer (`*`) not a double pointer (`**`), so get rid of the ampersand on `pos_dev`, I've updated my answer.  Your final `cudaMemcpy` operation also has similar issues and needs to be fixed.  Please review the documentation for the type of pointers expected for each parameter.

Comment: And the final `cudaMemcpy` in the code you have posted has the wrong direction specified.

Comment: Brilliant! This works! Sorry I wasn't careful enough in writing the back copy statement in the posted code. It is correct in my original cu file.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating your data as "array of structures", like

```
class Particle{
    public:
        float x;
        float v;
}

Particle foo[N];
```

which will lead to coalescing issues due to the data interleaving and for this reason you are trying to use `cudaMemcpy2D`. A more convenient solution in terms of bandwidth exploitation is allocating the data as "structures of arrays" as

```
class Particle{
    public:
        float x[N];
        float v[N];
}

Particle foo;
```

In this way, you will be able to avoid the use of `cudaMemcpy2D` and copy the data from host to device by a simple `cudaMemcpy`.

Comment: I thought of this, but including arrays in the class Particle defeats the purpose of creating such a class in the first place. My older code indeed had separate arrays for all the member variables, but it is becoming increasingly difficult to handle as the code gets more complex. - Thanks.