# How to copy a 2D array from Device to Host in Cuda?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, fft

I want to copy the results of a fft operation from device to host.

This is what happens.
The input is a pointer to a pointer to an float. the values get allocated during runtime. then it is transferred to the gpu and fft is calculated. Then the results are transferred
to to float2 2D array. But the result i get is wrong. It contains all zero. So how can I overcome this issue ?

```
#define NRANK 2
#define BATCH 10

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


float func(int,int){
              return 2.0f;  // some value get return. I have put a dummy value here
} 
int main()
    { 

    const size_t NX = 4;
    const size_t NY = 5;

    // Input array - host side
    float **a = new float*[NX];  

    for (int r = 0; r < NX; ++r)  // this can be also done on GPU
        {
        a[r] = new float[NY];
        for (int c = 0; c < NY; ++c)
            {            
                a[r][c] = func(r,c);         
            }
        }

    // Output array - host side  
    float2 c[NX][NY] = { 0 };


    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftComplex *data;   // Input and output arrays - device side
    int n[NRANK] = {NX, NY};

    // Transfer the data from host to device - have to do it like this becase
    // the array is a dynamic array
    cudaMalloc((void**)&data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY/2+1));
    for(int i=0; i<NX; ++i){
        cudaMemcpy(reinterpret_cast<float*>(data) + i*NY, a[i], sizeof(float)*NY,     
             cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     }

    /* Create a 2D FFT plan. */
    cufftPlanMany(&plan, NRANK, n,NULL, 1, 0,NULL, 1, 0,CUFFT_C2C,BATCH);
    cufftSetCompatibilityMode(plan, CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);
    cufftExecC2C(plan, data, data, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(c, data, sizeof(float2)*NX*NY, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Print the values of c  ---- ALL ARE 0
    for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
        {
        for (int j =0 ; j< NY; j++)
            {
            printf(" %f + %fi ",c[i][j].x,c[i][j].y);
            b
            }
        printf("\n");
        }


    cufftDestroy(plan);
    cudaFree(data);

    return 0;
    }
```

How could I solve this problem ?

---

### EDIT

After considering Robert Crovella's suggestion I modified the code as

```
// Output array - host side
float2 c[NX][NY + 2] ;

// New device side variable that will hold the result from the FFT size - twice as input {2 x NX*(NY/2 + 1)}
cufftComplex *data_out;
cudaMalloc((void**)&data_out, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY+2));

 /* Create a 2D FFT plan. */
cufftPlanMany(&plan, NRANK, n,NULL, 1, 0,NULL, 1, 0,CUFFT_C2C,BATCH);
cufftSetCompatibilityMode(plan, CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);
cufftExecC2C(plan, data, data_out, CUFFT_FORWARD);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
cudaError  cudaStat2 = cudaMemcpy(c, data_out, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY+2) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat2) << " ,\n";

for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
    {
    for (int j =0 ; j< NY; j++)
        {
        printf(" %f ,",c[i][j].x);

        }
    printf("\n");
    }
```

Now the output device matrix is 2 x sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY/2+1) and I have declared it as data_out. Then the host side matrix was also adjusted to hold NX*(NY+2) elements of float2. Now I don't get any errors from cudaMemcpy. But still I don't get the answer. What i get is an array of  1.#QNAN0 values.

So how can I solve this ?

Comment: no error checking?  both CUFFT and CUDA APIs have errors that may provide useful info.

Comment: @RobertCrovella : thanks for the tip. I checked the errors and the error is in  'cudaMemcpy(c, data, sizeof(float2)*NX*NY, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);' and the error is "invalid argument".

Comment: How can you copy `sizeof(float2)*NX*NY` bytes from `data` to `c` when you've only allocated `sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY/2+1)` bytes in `data` ?

Comment: I have added an answer one minute ago to your previous post. You may wish to take a look at that. You are forgetting to allocate space for the continous component of the FFT output, as also @RobertCrovella points out. You have to enlarge the size of `c`, not of `data`.

Comment: @JackOLantern : Thank you, I'll have a look.

Comment: @RobertCrovella : I followed your advice and I updated the question with what I did. But still the problem is not solved :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem described in your question title was fixed by making the modification I described in the comments.  After that, your code had other issues, not related to the copy back of results.

You're asking for a C2C transform of size `NX*NY`, but your input data size is only `sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY/2+1)`.  When I fix a variety of issues around your input data and it's size, I start to get results that are not NAN's in your code.

Also, it's not clear to me why you are allocating a size of `(NY+2)` in various places.  When I fix those errors I can get some kind of (non-NAN) result from your code:

```
$ cat t311.cu
#define NRANK 2
#define BATCH 10

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


using namespace std;


float func(int,int){
              return 2.0f;  // some value get return. I have put a dummy value here
}
int main()
    {

    const size_t NX = 4;
    const size_t NY = 5;

    // Input array - host side
    float **a = new float*[NX];

    for (int r = 0; r < NX; ++r)  // this can be also done on GPU
        {
        a[r] = new float[NY];
        for (int c = 0; c < NY; ++c)
            {
                a[r][c] = func(r,c);
            }
        }

    // Output array - host side
    float2 c[NX][NY] ;
    cufftHandle plan;

    cufftComplex *data;   // Input and output arrays - device side
    int n[NRANK] = {NX, NY};
    cudaMalloc((void**)&data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*NY);
    cudaMemset(data,0, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*NY);
    for(int i=0; i<NX; ++i){
        cudaMemcpy(reinterpret_cast<float*>(data) + i*NY, a[i], sizeof(float)*NY,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy H2D fail");
     }

  // New device side variable that will hold the result from the FFT size - twice as input {2 x NX*(NY/2 + 1)}
    cufftComplex *data_out;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&data_out, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY));
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc data_out fail");
   /* Create a 2D FFT plan. */
    if ((cufftPlanMany(&plan, NRANK, n,NULL, 1, 0,NULL, 1, 0,CUFFT_C2C,BATCH)) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) printf("cufft fail 1\n");
    if ((cufftSetCompatibilityMode(plan, CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE)) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) printf("cufft fail 2\n");
    if ((cufftExecC2C(plan, data, data_out, CUFFT_FORWARD)) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) printf("cufft fail 3\n") ;
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(c, data_out, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy D2H fail");

    for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
      {
      for (int j =0 ; j< NY; j++)
        {
        printf(" %f ,",c[i][j].x);

        }
      printf("\n");
      }

    cufftDestroy(plan);
    cudaFree(data);
    cudaCheckErrors("some error");
    return 0;
    }

$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t311 t311.cu -lcufft
$ ./t311
 20.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 ,
 20.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 ,
 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 ,
 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 ,
$
```

I'm not saying this fixes every possible issue or error this code might have, but the first two issues you've identified have been addressed.

I think the remaining problems stem from how you are populating the input data. You are putting an uneven number (NY = 5) of float values, laid over the top of a cufftComplex array. To me, that would give strange results. The first two complex values in each row (of data) will have real and complex components of 2. The third value will have a real component of 2, and an imaginary component of 0. The last two complex values will be all zero.

If you want to see one possible method to copy an array of `float` values into the real parts of an array of complex values with a single API call, consider `cudaMemcpy2D`, documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g17f3a55e8c9aef5f90b67cdf22851375) and with a recent example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803272/how-to-copy-variables-from-a-custom-class-array-on-host-into-a-float-array-on-de).  That example actually shows how to copy from a structure array to a `float` array, but doing the reverse (`float` array to structure array) uses a similar technique.  Something like this should work:

```
for(int i=0; i<NX; ++i){
    cudaMemcpy2D(data + i*NY, sizeof(cufftComplex), a[i], sizeof(float), sizeof(float), NY, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 }
```

If you have new questions/new problems, please post a new SO question to describe them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you said, it prints non-NAN values. But the results are wrong. I'll try to see what I can do and if I fails, I'll post a new question.  Regarding the NY+2 , since the input is NX*(NY/2+1)*sizeof(cufftComplex) ---[or NX*NY*sizeof(float) -- which is the size to hold a NX x NY float array], I multiplied the output size by 2. So NY/2 + 1 became NY + 2.

Comment: I think the remaining problems stem from how you are populating the input data.  You are putting an uneven number (NY = 5) of `float` values, laid over the top of a `cufftComplex` array.  To me that, would give strange results.   The first two complex values in each row (of `data`) will have real and complex components of 2.  The third value will have a real component of 2, and an imaginary component of 0.  The last two complex values will be all zero.

Comment: You were right. I changed cudaMemcpy to "cudaMemcpy((data) + i*NY, a[i], sizeof(cufftComplex)*NY,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);" and then changed the input host side array from type "float" to "float2". Anyhow, i would like to know is there a way to copy a "float" array directly to a "cufftComplex" array ?

Comment: If you could include your suggestion in the comment in your answer, i can accept as the correct answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer, including a suggestion of how to copy a `float` array to the real parts of a `cufftComplex` array (striding over the imaginary parts).  If you simply want to copy a `float` array to a `cufftComplex` array with no striding, then the simple cast you are using will accomplish that.